# detect if a click is real or emulated

Tags: windows, security, unity-game-engine

I wonder how I can detect if a click was made by the user using mouse vs clicks made by bot (emulated)

Most of my research suggests that it is impossible but I have seen many games that successfully blocked emulated clicks while having no impact on the real ones.

I can't seem to find any tutorials or articles on how to do this.

Based on my research all emulated clicks will likely be using either `SendInput` or `SendMessage` function. Both functions are defined inside `User32.dll`

So is it possible or safe to find the call stack of the event and block the event if I find `User32.dll` in the stack? How can I do that in `Unity`?

Comment: It depends on the type of game and what you are doing. If you can explain the type of game and why you want to do this then maybe there might be a way to do this

Comment: Well there is no "set' way to detect if someone is emulating clicks but you can watch for patterns.  Most auto clickers click so many times a second, if someone is clicking say 100 times a second, I think it is safe to say they are emulating clicks, or if they are click 30 times a second for a full minute straight it may be safe to say they are emulating clicks.  Also if they happen to be clicking every 50 ms, give or take a ms, they are also probably emulating clicks.  So you can't detect emulated clicks but you can detect patterns that suggest emulated clicks.

Comment: I am trying to learn. Always want to find out how others was able to do something that seems impossible. And pattern analysis is just too unreliable unless machine learning is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching is good enough to filter out really simple click bots. Those typically click in precisely the same location, and the interval would be regular within 1/10th of a second. I'd start there, and then develop more advanced algorithms as you target and learn how cheaters are interacting with your game client. Like others said, it depends on your game.

Comment: Checking for interval timings would only root out the most rudimentary of bots. Bots normally click the exact same location however, I would suggest keeping an array of click coordinates and invalidate any clicks that have too many duplicate coordinates in that stored array. That'd be a start anyhow.

Comment: I also advise checking for instantaneous mouse movement.

Comment: I have seen many games successfully blocked all the emulated inputs. (except a ring0 fake driver one ofc) Which proves that there is a way better way to do this than pattern matching and I want to know how they did it. That was the main goal of the question